# In django, how can I get detailed error information in ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django

I'm learning web programming with Django. Currently I'm trying to build a webpage that users can update their user profile (such as e-mail, nickname). I'm using ajax to process this data. But I just came up with a question that how can I get detailed ajax error information?

For example, an user wants to update his nickname or e-mail, but the nickname or e-mail he posts is already existing in the database. In ajax, I use `error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}` to get the error information. But I just get something like "500 Internal server error". However, in the browser console I can see whether "nickname" or "e-mail" is duplicated. So I wonder how I can get to know which one is duplicated?

My **view.py** is:

```
@login_required
def edit_usr_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    objs = UserProfile.objects.filter(usr=user)
    usr_objs = UserProfile.objects.get(usr=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():
            usr_objs.nickname = request.POST.get('nickname')
            usr_objs.email = request.POST.get('email')
            usr_objs.save()
    return render(request, 'account/edit_profile.html', {'objs':objs})
```

my **ajax** code is:

```
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'./',
                data:{
                    async: false,
                    nickname:usr_nickname,
                    email:usr_email,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },
                success:function () {
                    alert('New profile saved!')
                    //window.location.reload()
                },
                error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error! Please check your entry and try again!')
                }
            })
```

I'll be very appreciated if you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a question for the beginners.In general, the back-end part should determine if everything's just fine and send a status code / result / etc. to the JavaScript part.

```
#THIS CODE MAY NEEDS SOME MODIFY TO PUT IN USE.

@login_required
def edit_usr_profile(request):
    # AN RESULT DICT THAT SAVES YOUR STATUS INFO
    result = collections.OrderedDict()
    result['code'] = "-1"
    result['message'] = ""
    result['data'] = ""

    user = request.user
    objs = UserProfile.objects.filter(usr=user)
    usr_objs = UserProfile.objects.get(usr=user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():
            try:
                usr_objs.nickname = request.POST.get('nickname')
                usr_objs.email = request.POST.get('email')
                usr_objs.save()
                # CHANGE THE INFO AND STATUS AS YOUR WISH
                result['code'] = "1"
                result['message'] = "Success"
            except Exception as e:
                # SAVES THE ERROR INFO 
                result['code'] = "-1"
                result['message'] = "Failed with error:"+str(e)
    # RETURN THE RESULT DICT 
    return render(request, 'account/edit_profile.html', {'objs':objs,'resultInfo':result})
```

Then you just need to judge the 'code' part in your JavaScript and determine whether to show the info or not.

Usually, web applications are not supposed to have 500 errors as part of it's function.Try to avoid it with the 'Try-catch' mechanism.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have changed my view.py as you suggested. It finally works!!!